# Socket.IO and Complex JSON with Node.js, jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm having a ton of trouble with this.  I'm trying to make it so that when I move a square-div, the position of that div is relayed to another page via Socket.IO, so that the div moves in realtime.  Only problem is that I don't have a clue how to do this!  The documentation over at http://socket.io only confused me.

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydiv").draggable().mousemove(function(){
        var coord = $(this).position();
        $("#left").val(coord.left);
        $("#top").val(coord.top);
    });
});
```

html:

```
X: <input type="text" value="50" id="left"/>
Y: <input type="text" value="50" id="top"/>

<div id="element"></div>
```

​

​I don't even know where to start with socket.io, please help!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.IO consists of two parts:

1. A server program that can send and receive data from clients
2. A client script that can connect to the Socket.IO server and send and receive data

So, first of all, you need a server. Here's one that listens on port `8080` and when a client connects, it waits for an `receive_position` event from it, and when it gets one, broadcasts that position to all the rest of the connected clients via an `update_position` event.

There is also some code to serve an `index.htm` file when the root URL (`/`) is visited. Most of this code is from the Socket.IO "How to Use" page; if the non-Socket.IO code doesn't make any sense, you may want to brush up on your Node.js fundamentals.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

var lastPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // whatever default data

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('update_position', lastPosition);
  socket.on('receive_position', function (data) {
     lastPosition = data;
     socket.broadcast.emit('update_position', data); // send `data` to all other clients
  });
});
```

Now that your server is set up, you need some client-side scripting to send and receive the positions of the div. Put this code in your `index.htm` file.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect();
    socket.on('update_position', function (data) {
      var x = data.x;
      var y = data.y;
      // jquery code to move div here
    });

    $("#mydiv").draggable().mousemove(function(){
      var coord = $(this).position();
      $("#left").val(coord.left);
      $("#top").val(coord.top);
      socket.emit('receive_position', { x: coord.left, y: coord.top });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This code sends a `receive_position` event when the div is dragged; the server gets this event, and sends an `update_position` event with the same x and y values to all other clients; when they receive this data, they update the div.

Hope this helps get you started; let me know in the comments if you have any questions.

Comment: is it okay if I use this/variant of this in my application for a profit?

Comment: the weird thing is that it isn't two-way. It seems like the latest localhost page opened is the one that controls them all.  How can I make them all equal to each other?  I think it might have something to do with the default positioning, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Sure, I don't mind what you do with this code. The last page open will have the default positions; you'll either need to render the page with the last known position already set, or send an `update_position` event to the newly connected client with the last known positions in the `io.sockets.on('connection')` callback.

Comment: how would it know what the last position was?

Comment: When it comes in to the server, store it away in a variable.

Comment: io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('receive_position', function (data) {
     var rp = data;
     socket.broadcast.emit('update_position', data); // send `data` to all other clients
  });
});
Like this?  But what would you do in index.html?

Comment: perhaps whenever a page is opened, it would automatically ask the server for data, and if none is given, then none is given, but if not, then it is given the data.. I guess that would work

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer with code that remembers the last known position and automatically sends the last known position when a new client connects (the client does not have to ask for it).

Comment: Where did you find documentation for socket.io?  I'm trying to prompt the user to give me a new ID, and then replace that long number socket.io generates with the new ID.  However, no matter how good my guesses are, I end up with undefined

Comment: also, when I put my cursor over the square and move it, but don't drag the square, it sends data to the server, even though the square is stationary.  I think it might be a jquery problem with .draggable()

Comment: My Socket.IO knowledge comes from the Socket.IO homepage, their [GitHub readme](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io), and reading the source. The reason for your mouse issue is that you're binding to the `mousemove` event on the draggable; instead, you should be using the `drag` event -- check the [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Comment: The full working example - including the drag event - is in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/4565681 Thanks @BrandonTilley