# draggable and droppable jquery socket.io

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, websocket, socket.io, drag-and-drop

With the use of **"Jquery"** I have been trying to make a simple drag and drop system. The **"Jquery"** drag and drop system I want to make works very well. It is created with a draggable and droppable function. Like shown here.

```js
$(function() {  
$( ".this-div" ).draggable({
        grid: [ 5, 5 ],
       appendTo: '#droppable',
        containment: $('#droppable'),
       cursor: 'hand',
        tolerance: 'fit',
       revertDuration: 100,
       revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone'
        
    });

    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: ".this-div",
            drop: function( event, ui ) { 
                ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#droppable'); 
     }
}); 
});
```

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#droppable{
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.this-div{
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #444;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

aside{
float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Draggable and droppable - Jquery and Socket.io</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="droppable"></section>
        <aside><div class="this-div">Test</div></aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result can be seen as picture here. [click here to see picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGlr0.png)

Now what I want to know, is the easiest way to emit the drop of a cloned div in the droppable section to other clients. The target is to make all connected users on the page see the dropped clone in realtime. I have been searching for an example to get an idea about how to make this, all over the internet and found nothing useable, beside this [Socket.IO and Complex JSON with Node.js, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865167/socket-io-and-complex-json-with-node-js-jquery), so i know it's possible to move a div around in realtime, but is it possible to clone in realtime? In some how I think I will need to save the position of the dropped clone like drikk0 does, in the sample *linked over here*. So to make it short, what I want is people to drag and drop a clone which in realtime will be seen by all other connected users. But my problem is that I can't figure out how to do it in the best possible way, with a combination of jquery and socket.io.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So this  problem would create a number of little issues. It is possible and as you said, you will need to store the position someplace (most likely a database) that can allow other clients to gather that data. Do you just want the result stored? I would suggest looking at jquery, ajax, php, and mysql.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes what I want is the result stored and then if possible received by all clients (later on a choosen usergroup), so they can see the stored result. (by result i'm thinking of the html and css - markup, and ofcourse position). The choosen usergroup could be made by a connecting string (like agar.io) or by a login, but this part is not important right now. The important part right now is getting the drag and drop, to show changes to all clients for now. And make it possible to actually clone the div everytime it's dragged and dropped into the droppable. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide that you have tried so far? What type of environment are you using? Database?

Comment: Basically, the presenter client using AJAX, can update a table in a database (using server side scripting). The viewers then use AJAX to check for updates. And if found, updates the view the viewers have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I think that i'm going the jquery, ajax, php, and mysql way instead, as you mentioned. So yea, if I get any problems, then I will provide you what I have been trying so far, if it's okay with you? i'm going to start working out a solution tomorrow :)

Comment: Cool. Just here to help so it's all good by me.

Answer (score 0):

(this is not the final solution but just a step on the right way)

After some research and work, I come up with this pretty simple solution on getting the individual position on the single dropped clone. Now what I need to understand is how I can send this position each time a clone is dropped (into the droppable section) to a Mysqli Database (or something like). So that I can save the change and show it to all connected users, in realtime. Here you can see what I have so far.

```js
$(function(){

        $(".this-div").draggable({
            grid: [ 5, 5 ],
            appendTo: '#droppable',
            containment: $('#droppable'),
            cursor: 'hand',
            tolerance: 'fit',
            revertDuration: 100,
            revert: 'invalid',
            helper: 'clone' 
        });

        $("#droppable").droppable({
          accept: '.this-div',

          drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper.clone().appendTo('#droppable');
            
            leftPosition  = ui.offset.left - $(this).offset().left;
            topPosition   = ui.offset.top - $(this).offset().top;

            //Debug current dropped position
            $("#top").val(topPosition);
            $("#left").val(leftPosition);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#droppable{
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.this-div{
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #444;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
}

aside{
float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pass Jquery Drop To MYSQLI DB</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <!-- Jquery Implimentation -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="top" value="Top Position">
        <input id="left" value="Left Position">
        <section id="droppable"></section>
        <aside>
            <div class="this-div">Test</div>
        </aside>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!